# Android ListView with Query

Tags: java, equals

I have multiple queries to get all messages within a certain chat between two specific users. I want to be able to also say in a for loop,only do an action if the username is equal to the current user. I want to do this because for example, I am making chat bubbles and for the current user,and want the text objects that are from the non current user to say "From: Second User",and the ones from the current user to say "From: Current User". Anything I use the for loop even with an if statement it uses the if statements actual logic,saying if something is true,do this. How can I fix this problem? Thanks a ton! Here is my code. P.S. I know this is not the way to do it,but just giving you an example of how I want it to work.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageList = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");

                messageList.whereEqualTo("to_user",user.getUsername());
                messageList.whereEqualTo("from_user",recipient_Name);

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageList2 = ParseQuery.getQuery("Messages");
                messageList2.whereEqualTo("to_user",recipient_Name);
                messageList2.whereEqualTo("from_user",user.getUsername());

                List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
                queries.add(messageList);
                queries.add(messageList2);

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
                mainQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(e == null){
                            for (ParseObject message : objects) {

                                if(message.get("from_user") == user.getCurrentUser()){
                                 adapter.add("From: Current User");
                                    }else if(message.get("from_user") != 
                                 user.getCurrentUser()){
                             adapter.add("From: Second User");
                                  }
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `==` to compare objects. This is a no-go in Java.

In Java you should use the `equals` method of `Object` to compare objects.

Your code:

```
if(message.get("from_user") == user.getCurrentUser()) {
    adapter.add("From: Current User");
} else if(message.get("from_user") != user.getCurrentUser()) {
    adapter.add("From: Second User");
}
```

should be changed to:

```
if(message.get("from_user").equals(user.getCurrentUser())) {
    adapter.add("From: Current User");
} else if(message.get("from_user").equals(user.getCurrentUser())) {
    adapter.add("From: Second User");
}
```

See http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/ for clarification on `equals` vs `==` or just [google it](https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20equals%20vs%20%3D%3D) :-)

Also on a side-note: fix your formatting of your question and if someone hasn't commented or answered your question for a while, maybe the question needs re-phrasing.